# Creating temporary files with PHP

Tags: php, image, temporary

My PHP site is just something like CGI: it parse parameters, call application with provided parameters and then serve result to user.

My application output is image (to be more precise: jpeg image). Now I just save image to some accessible to user directory and return link.

Problem is, that after some time this directory will be full of images.

Is there any easy solution to read this image file from disk, provide it to user browser and then delete it?

Comment: If you delete a file its no longer remotely visible - why not run a script to remove files older than x days - or return the image data instead of a file

Comment: I agree with @ManseUK... If you delete the files right away, you run the risk of removing it too soon.  A cron job of some sort to keep that directory cleaned up would probably be best.

Answer (score 0):

Why not, rather than providing the link,have a script that sends a header("Content-type: image/jpeg") and then the image itself?